# python - get bones location in pose mode in world-space coordinates

Tags: python, objects, coordinates, pose-mode

I want to get the offsets between a bone's coordinates in pose mode and its coordinates in object mode.

My exact situation is that I have multiple rigged characters with same the orientations, but different scales. I want to modify the bones' locations in pose mode but in object world coordinates. So now I have problems with offsets between pose mode coordinates and object mode coordinates, and also scale.
Is there a way to have a single world coordinate system with the same scale, offset and orientation for all objects and bones in pose mode?